# var_dump shortcut access in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, var-dump

how can I get quick access to var_dump in Visual Studio Code editor? For example: I enter `vd` letters and after pressing the Enter key I get `var_dump("");`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS Code has a global snippets file, as well as snippet files for each language. You can choose to add the snippet in either one.

#### Add it to the global file

1) File-->Preferences-->User snippets

2) Select New Global Snippets file

3) Save it as global.code-snippets (or name it anything with the extention code-snippets)

4) Remove everything then paste this in:

```
{
  "Var_Dump": {
    "prefix": "vd",
    "scope": "php",
    "body": [
      "var_dump($1);",
      "$2"
    ],
    "description": "var_dump"
  }
}
```

#### Or Add it to the php file

1) File-->Preferences-->User snippets-->php.json

2) Remove everything then paste this in:

```
{
  "Var_Dump": {
    "prefix": "vd",
    "body": [
      "var_dump($1);",
      "$2"
    ],
      "description": "var_dump"
    }
}
```

#### Usage

Go to a php file (make sure it has opening `<?php` tag. Type "vd" and hit <kbd>tab</kbd>

#### Not working?

- VS Code says you don't need to restart your editor, however I found this helped.
- Snippets/intellisense can take some time to come up. Wait for the snippet to show up before hitting <kbd>tab</kbd>. You are waiting for this: [image]

More info and options can be found on [this VS Code help page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets).

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet. [HERE](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) you can read how to make it.

> You can define your own snippets for specific languages. To open up a snippet file for editing, open User Snippets under File > Preferences (Code> Preferences on Mac) and select the language for which the snippets should appear.
>   Snippets are defined in a JSON format and stored in a per user (languageId).json file. For example, Markdown snippets go in a markdown.json file.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.